# Reponse.Write() in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I am trying to use ListItem related to DropDowList control it is not showing in intelligence and the thing is I should add  items to the DropDownList . I checked for namespaces and assemblies which are required for this context but something is wrong.
Finally i want to send response back to the client, I used Response.Write() method but the same problem not showing in intelligence due to that error. So please explain ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void ddlOption_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
    {
        float num1=float.Parse(textNum1.Text.Trim());
        float num2=float.Parse(textNum2.Text.Trim());
        float Result=0;
        switch(ddlOption.SelectedIndex>0)
        {
            case 1:Result=num1+num2;
                    break;
            case 2:Result=num1-num2;
                break;
            case 3:Result=num1*num2;
                break;
            case 4: Result = num1 / num2;
                break;

        }
       textResult.Text = Result.ToString();
    }

    else
    Response.Write();
```

Comment: Paste your code......

Comment: Do you get errors when you build your code?  Paste the errors you get if so.

Comment: You're not writing anything to the HTTP Response. `Response.Write();` should be `Response.Write("some response here");` Also you seem to be missing a lot of code in your question.

Comment: I answered before you posted your code, but I agree with @siva that there seems to be a lot code missing from what you posted.  The standalone `else` that Darshana pointed out is a related disconcerting clue.

Comment: Ok boss it is solved and Executed,thanks for your help

Comment: Great to hear.  If one of the answers to your question fixed your issue, be sure to mark it accepted so that others who read your question will know; consider upvoting any answers that may have helped you resolve your issue; and if you solved your issue differently than any of the answers to your question, consider following up with a self-answer to share how you fixed it.  BTW, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if **else** required just before the Response.Write();

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing a reference to `System.Web.dll`.

Your project needs to reference this assembly for your code's `System.Web` & `System.Web.UI.WebControls` `using` directives and `Response.Write` & `DropDownList` references to resolve and for related IntelliSense to work.

To add a reference to `System.Web.dll`, right-click on the *References* folder in your project, then *Add Reference...* in the context menu that appears.  In the Reference Manager dialog that opens, click *Assemblies*, select *System.Web*, and click the *Add* button.